# How copying text with replace in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have done to copying text with keyup, but when i add replace function the copy not work this my code

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="name">
<input id="alias" type="text" name="alias">
```

javascript

```
$("#name").keyup(function(){
        var name = $('#name');
        var alias = $('#alias');
        alias.val(name.val());
 });
```

when i change to

```
 $("#name").keyup(function(){
            var name = $('#name');
            var alias = $('#alias');
var copy = name.replace(" ", "-"); 
alias.val(copy.val());
     });
```

this not give anything.

thanks

Comment: What you need to doing the replace??

Comment: `var copy = name.val().replace(" ", "-"); alias.val(copy);` you're missing `val()`.

Comment: i have edit the text. i won copy and replace the input with id="name" to id="alias" and replace "space" with "-"

Comment: thankyou @alejandro thats work

Comment: but why when i enter more space and replace not run egain?

Comment: @Angel'sWing's you can do it as many times as you want, you could even do it inside an iterative loop (`while` or other one). Just make sure you work **on the value** you got by `val()` and not on the jQuery object itself.

Comment: I'd advice against using a loop to replace the characters, just use a regular expression to replace all occurrences of a character.

Comment: @Atticus agreed, but looks like he's just starting to learn. Adding regexp to a begginner is just too overkill for what he wants to do, in my opinion.

Comment: @AlejandroIván to each their own. I feel like that starts things off on the wrong foot. We're not talking about complex regular expressions, we're talking about a single character pattern match, which is also a fantastic introduction for solving common problems such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `name.replace(..)` - but remember, `name` is the `jQuery` element, *not* the value of the field.

You want to do

```
var copy = name.val().replace(' ', '-');
alias.val(copy);
```

Also note that `.replace(' ', '-')` will not replace *all* occurrences of `-`, only the first. You want to use a regular expression for what you're searching for

```
.replace(/\s/g, '-');
```

Will replace all occurrences of whitespace with a dash

Comment: but why only replace one space when enter more space and not work again

Comment: I actually edited this answer to include that, refresh the page and you'll see the explanation for using regular expressions to match _all_ whitespace occurrences.

Comment: If regular expressions are too weird to him, he could also use an iterative loop to replace... something like `var copy = name.val(); while ( true ) { var old = copy; copy = copy.replace(' ', '-'); if ( copy == old ) break; }`

Comment: thank you @Atticus thats work to replace more space :)

Comment: @AlejandroIván IMO that should be seen as an antipattern. The best alternative to using a regular expression would be @NadimulDeCj's example of `split`ing the string by whitespaces and `join`ing by `-`

Comment: @Alejandro Iván thankyou to, for give another answer

Comment: @Angel'sWing's yeah, no problem dude. But take in consideration that Atticus' answer is better for the future. You should **definitely** learn regular expressions for these kind of issues. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

So you need to do this.

```
$("#name").keyup(function(){
     var name = $('#name');
     var alias = $('#alias');
     var copy = name.val().replace(" ", "-"); 
     alias.val(copy);
 });
```

If you just want to handle spaces:

```
var copy = name.val().replace(/ +/g, '-');
```

If you want to replace tabs and new lines as well:

```
var copy = name.val().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
```

As **Alejandro** said before me, but i am going to give this solution.

Comment: but why only replace one space when enter more space and not work again

Comment: Change this line and try again: `var copy =  name.val().replace(/ +/g, '-')`

Answer (score 1):

Below code works perfect

```
$("#name").keyup(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var alias = $('#alias').val();
    var copy = name.split(' ').join('-')
    $('#alias').val(copy);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `val()` and that string copy is totally unneccesary so this code will work just fine

```
$("#name").keyup(function(){
var name = $('#name');
var alias = $('#alias'); 
alias.val(name.val().replace(" ","-"));
});
```

I tried it and it worked fine for me..so go ahead and use it..  :D